# How to populate one dropdown from the other in django dynamically using AJAX/DAJAX/DAJAXICE/Simple Javascript?

Tags: ajax, django, drop-down-menu, dajaxice, dajax

I have searched enough of the examples but couldn't get the satisfactory result. Please explain with all the necessary code. I am very poor at AJAX. I tried to use DAJAXICE in my code and got little success but didn't work with passing parameters. 
I am using Django 1.6 Dajaxice 0.7 Dajax 0.9.
Any way you feel the easiest is okay but please explain with all the code.
TIA.

Comment: There are plenty of examples online. Please try at least some solution and come back if its not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a simple Django view to fetch some data with AJAX, take a look at [django-braces AjaxResponseMixin](https://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/other.html#ajaxresponsemixin). Below is a code sample which returns list of objects ids and their names:

```
from django.views.generic import View
from braces import views

class SomeView(views.JSONResponseMixin, views.AjaxResponseMixin, View):
    def get_ajax(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_objects = MyObject.objects.all()
        json_dict = {
            'ids': [x.id for x in my_objects],
            'names': [x.name for x in my_objects]
        }
        return self.render_json_response(json_dict)
```

Then use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make the query from your template and populate your fields.

If you're not familiar with Class Based Views, your url for this view could be:

```
url('^objects/(?P<some_id>[0-9]+)/$', SomeView.as_view())
```

then in `get_ajax` you can access `self.kwargs['some_id']` to filter objects.

Comment: Can you help me with the template code? The view code is completely fine. Up till now I used to send requests from the templates by using action property of the form tag. I couldn't send the request to a view by using the url tag of the AJAX function. Can you please explain that code as well.?